# Restcomm Sipservlets docker with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, restcomm, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am looking at running the tomcat 8 version of RestComm sipservlets within a docker container. The main concern I have is passing the public IP as an environmental variable so that is used in sip messaging. Additionally, I also like to know how the internal IP can be passed to  the server.xml connector definition via an environmental variable as well. I am currently using restcomm-sip-servlets-4.0.75

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the new Docker Quick Start guide available [here](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.html).

Hope that helps!